# How to start ActiveMQ WebConsole at the same server every time?

Tags: activemq-classic, apache-zookeeper

I have 3 virtual machines, each one of them running `zookeeper` and `activemq`.
Every time I start `ActiveMQ`, the `ActiveMQ WebConsole` starts in a different server. I wanto to start the ActiveMQ WebConsole at the same server everytime, so I don't need to figure out which of them is running the `webconsole` through the logs.

This is how my `jetty.xml` is configured:

```
<bean id="jettyPort" class="org.apache.activemq.web.WebConsolePort" init-method="start">
         <!-- the default port number for the web console -->
    <property name="host" value="0.0.0.0"/>
    <property name="port" value="8161"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible as the embedded web server runs on the broker that is the master.

You can look at alternative web consoles that allows remote management, such as hawtio that can connect to remote servers. You can start hawtio on your local computer, or have it run on some other host, or start it separately on one of those 3 nodes etc.

- http://hawt.io/

Answer (score 1):

Running a local Hawt.io like Claus advices is a great option.

If you want to stick with the web console, you can actually have it connect to the current master broker.

You will need to start the console in non embedded mode and set (at least) three system properties. That is, typically this involves deploying the [web-console .war](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/activemq/activemq-web-console/5.13.2/activemq-web-console-5.13.2.war) inside a Tomcat or similar.

```
webconsole.jms.url=failover:(tcp://serverA:61616,tcp://serverB:61616)
webconsole.jmx.url=service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://serverA:1099/jmxrmi,service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://serverB:1099/jmxrmi
webconsole.type=properties
```

[An old article](https://dzone.com/articles/activemq-configuring-multiple) that discuss using the embedded web consoles for failover as well. I don't know if it applies in all details to current versions.